# Safest way to divide unsigned long int by unsigned long long

Tags: c++, division

What is the safest way to divide B by A, assuming the following types for each of them?

```
unsigned long long A;
unsigned long int B;
```

I am already using the following line to do that. It works fine, however, sometimes it fails with the Segmentation Faults.

```
double C;
C= double(B)/double(A);
```

Thanks

Comment: "sometimes"? What times?

Comment: The safest way is to not do it and assume the result is 42

Comment: "It works fine" and "sometimes it fails with the Segmentation Faults" leads me to believe "fine" isn't exactly an accurate adjective. I'm fairly confident that so long as `A` is never zero, the above line of code could run repeatedly without issue. So the related question to you is: what object(s) are A, B, or C members of, and how long before this code executes was said-object(s) deleted or otherwise returned as a dangling reference?

Comment: I am not sure, this line is a part of a huge code and replacing the values of B and A with constants solves the Seg Fault. So, I doubt that the problem must be related to the way the division is performed.

Comment: Segmentation fault is NOT caused by a divide instruction - it is caused by a memory access to an invalid memory address. Using `double` to store a `long long` is not advisable, as you may loose precision [an IEEE-754 float has 53 bits, long long is 64 bits (or larger)].

Comment: I am gonna delete the question if you are sure about the division.

Comment: Of course, if you are using `C` to index into an array or something like that, and the result of B/A is out of range in some way, then who knows what will happen. But I'm 100% sure that a the divide itself will not make a Segfault.

Comment: Thank you all. I am gonna see where the values of C are refering to.

Comment: You said if you replace A and B with constants the fault doesn't happen. if it happens *on that specific line* when A and B are members, I submit my original assumption is accurate. The object A an B are members of .."isn't". If it faults somewhere *after* then the *usage* of the result is the issue. And *both* can be determined one way or another if you **run this in a debugger and let it crash**.

Answer (score 4):

(Firstly, `unsigned long int` is the same as `unsigned long`)

Data type promotion rules mean that when evaluating `A / B`, `B` is promoted to `unsigned long long` and the division performed in integer arithmetic; i.e. any remainder is lost.

Casting either A`or B` to `double` causes the operation to be performed in floating point `double`. (But note that casting a `long long` type to a `double` can result in precision loss.)

Rest assured that `C = double(B) / double(A);` will *not* cause a segmentation fault. You must have memory corruption / other undefined behaviour prior to this statement. I suspect you've messed up your stack.

Answer (score 2):

These are ints so no need to cast to a double unless you're actually expecting a floating point fractional result (i.e. you probably do want to cast, but that has nothing to do with your fault).

More than likely you're getting errors because of divide by zero.

Comment: FYI, a divide by zero error is not the same as a segmentation fault.  The OP is getting a segmentation fault.